# Bakoma TeX Word command line file opening

Tags: bakoma

I am new to LaTeX/Bakoma TeX Word, and I have a query about Bakoma TeX Word.

I can open a TeX file in using `texword.exe` from the command line:

```
C:\BaKoMa TeX\BIN\WIN32>texopen.exe D:\RS\RSTA\gms333\uiii.tex
```

and this works perfectly.

What I would like to do is open a TeX file in Bakoma TeX Word in this way and jump directly to a line number/column number I specify.

In WinEdt the same result can be obtained using

```
C:\yandy\WINEDT\WinEdt.exe -F [Open('D:\xx\333\aa.tex');SelPar(59,8)]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @SathishV I've edited your question to I hope make it clearer: I do hope this is OK.

Comment: I suspect you may struggle to get answers here: BaKoMa is not that widely-used compared with free TeX systems, and this is a very specific requirement. Have you asked the BaKoMa support people: command line options for GUI applications are not always well documented.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer by posting your question on the [BaKoMa support site](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/menu/support.php) (under FAQ). And if the function you want is not currently supported, you can make a feature request in their support site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is really a BaKoMa feature request.
